# Scaffold Identity UI in ASP.NET Core 2.1 and add Global Filter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have a ASP.NET Core 2.1 application in which I am using Identity scaffolding as explained over [here](https://www.talkingdotnet.com/how-to-scaffold-identity-ui-in-asp-net-core-2-1/)

Now I have a Global Filter for OnActionExecuting

```
public class SmartActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And in startup.cs I configured filter as below

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new AddHeaderAttribute("Author", "HaBo")); // an instance
            options.Filters.Add(typeof(SmartActionFilter)); // by type
            // options.Filters.Add(new SampleGlobalActionFilter()); // an instance
        })
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
        .AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
            options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
        });
}
```

This Filter get used across all action methods but not for the one's in Identity Area. How can I have global filter work for all pages in Identity Area?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the opening paragraph of [Filters in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2), you'll see the following note:

> **Important**
>
> This topic does **not** apply to Razor Pages. ASP.NET Core 2.1 and later supports [**IPageFilter**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.ipagefilter?view=aspnetcore-2.0) and [**IAsyncPageFilter**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.iasyncpagefilter?view=aspnetcore-2.0) for Razor Pages. For more information, see [**Filter methods for Razor Pages**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/filter?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

This explains why your `SmartActionFilter` implementation is only executing for actions and not for page handlers. Instead, you should implement `IPageFilter` or `IAsyncPageFilter` as suggested in the note:

```
public class SmartActionFilter : IPageFilter
{
    public void OnPageHandlerSelected(PageHandlerSelectedContext ctx) { }

    public void OnPageHandlerExecuting(PageHandlerExecutingContext ctx)
    {
        // Your logic here.
    }

    public void OnPageHandlerExecuted(PageHandlerExecutedContext ctx)
    {
        // Example requested in comments on answer.
        if (ctx.Result is PageResult pageResult)
        {
            pageResult.ViewData["Property"] = "Value";
        }

        // Another example requested in comments.
        // This can also be done in OnPageHandlerExecuting to short-circuit the response.
        ctx.Result = new RedirectResult("/url/to/redirect/to");
    }
}
```

Registering `SmartActionFilter` is still done in the same way as shown in your question (using `MvcOptions.Filters`).

If you want to run this for both actions *and* page handlers, it looks like you might need to implement both `IActionFilter` and `IPageFilter`.

Comment: Is there a way I can set ViewBag here? in this filter?

Comment: You can't access `ViewBag` directly, but you can add properties to `ViewData` that will be readable using `ViewBag` in the page's cshtml.

Comment: That helped. Wish if I can also control Redirect from here